# How to convert string from list into integer, and then substract?

Tags: python, pandas, list, data-manipulation

I want to substract the two numbers found in each string values from the list array and convert into an integer.

current df:

```
                     pbp
0   ['0-0', '0-2', '0-4']
1   ['0-0', '2-0', '4-2']
2   ['0-0', '0-1', '0-2']
```

expected df:

```
            pbp
0   [0, -2, -4]
1   [0, 2, 2]
2   [0, -1, -2]
```

tried: 
`df[['pbp']].applymap(lambda x: x.strip()).applymap(ast.literal_eval)`

```
               pbp
0   [0-0, 0-2, 0-4]
1   [0-0, 2-0, 4-2]
2   [0-0, 0-1, 0-2]
```

I just don't know how to substract them

Comment: How did you get such dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: You could apply eval to the rows of the dataframe, although  I am not sure that is recommended

Comment: @connectyourcharger `df[['pbp']].applymap(lambda x: x.strip()).applymap(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: Add that line to your post

Comment: You can use `df['pbd'].apply(lambda xs: [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in xs])`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and naive way to achieve what you want:

```
def subtract_list(my_list):
    result=[]
    for val in my_list:
        numbers = val.split('-')
        res = int(numbers[0] )- int(numbers[1])
        result.append(res)
    print(result)
    return result
```

Calling the method would return:

```
subtract_list(['0-0', '0-2', '0-4'])
```

[0, -2, -4]

Comment: Apologies,the question did not mention it to be a dataframe when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

While not stated in the question this answer can cover multiple math operations using a `pattern` and `re.split`.

```
import re

def compute(data):
    output = []
    for entry in data:
        equation = re.split('([\/|\-|\+|\*\*|\*|%])', entry)

        result = {
           '*' : lambda e: int(e[0]) * int(e[2]),
           '+' : lambda e: int(e[0]) + int(e[2]),
           '-' : lambda e: int(e[0]) - int(e[2]),
           '\/': lambda e: int(e[0]) / int(e[2]),
           '%' : lambda e: int(e[0]) % int(e[2]),
        }[equation[1]](equation)

        output.append(result)
    return output
```